# Alternate to virtual function call on base destructor

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

So, I've written the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractMachine
{
public:
    void powerOn();
    void powerOff();
    bool isPoweredOn();

    virtual ~AbstractMachine();

protected:
    virtual void powerOnImpl() = 0;
    virtual void powerOffImpl() = 0;

private:
    bool m_isPoweredOn;
};

bool AbstractMachine::isPoweredOn()
{
    return m_isPoweredOn;
}

void AbstractMachine::powerOn()
{
    if (!m_isPoweredOn)
    {
        powerOnImpl();
        m_isPoweredOn = true;
    }
}

void AbstractMachine::powerOff()
{
    if (m_isPoweredOn)
    {
        powerOffImpl();
        m_isPoweredOn = false;
    }
}

AbstractMachine::~AbstractMachine()
{
    powerOff();       // (1)
    std::cout << "Destroying a machine" << std::endl;
}

class AirConditioner : public AbstractMachine
{
protected:
    void powerOnImpl() override;
    void powerOffImpl() override;
public:
    ~AirConditioner();
};

void AirConditioner::powerOnImpl()
{
    std::cout << "Turning on air conditioner" << std::endl;
}

void AirConditioner::powerOffImpl()
{
    std::cout << "Turning off air conditioner" << std::endl;
}

AirConditioner::~AirConditioner()
{
    //powerOff();        // (2)
    std::cout << "Destroing air conditioner" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    AbstractMachine *machine = new AirConditioner();
    machine->powerOn();
    delete machine;
}
```

This is going to fail, because derived object is already destroyed when the base destructor calls derived function on (1).

This runs fine when I comment (1) and uncomment (2), but what I want to do here is to **automatically and always turn off the machine before it gets destroyed, though the 'power off' action depends on the custom machine**.

Is there a better way of doing this?
Should I just give up?
Or is it not even the right way of a design on OOP?

Comment: Invoke powerOff outside destructor before you call delete. EDIT: oh you want it to automatically destroy good question

Comment: Well, you can't change the order of destructors. You could create some kind of manager class, and just call powerOff in your manager/wrapper class and don't call powerOff in destructor at all

Comment: This may work under certain conditions only: make `operator delete` of your `class AbstractMachine` `private` (to prevent accidental usage). Introduce a function `destroy(AbstractMachine*)` which is `friend` of `class AbstractMachine`. This function can call `AbstractMachine::powerOff()` before calling `delete`. One draw-back (at first glance), it does not work if instances are not created by `new`. This can be forced by making constructors protected and providing a `create()` function as well. (The latter, I saw e.g. in gtkmm.)

Answer (score 0):

As you observe, when the base class constructor runs, the derived class part is no longer around.  There's no trick to make that not so, so there's no way to just do it all in (or from) the base destructor.

You just need to figure what part of turning off belongs to each level, and have each destructor take care of its own level.  When the object is destroyed, each level's destructor is run, bottom to top, so everything gets done.  I think that would be the OOP approach.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations :

1. If you are potentially running complex logic in a destructor it is often worth taking a step back. Since `AbstractMachine` has no idea what logic will be executed in `powerOffImpl()`, the programmer cannot be sure that exceptions will not be thrown by a derived class, and destructors should always avoid throwing exceptions. Better for `AirConditioner` to call `powerOffImpl()` in its destructor directly, then the implementor of `AirConditioner` is aware of any risk of exceptions and can code to mitigate this. Also the implementor can choose not to call `powerOffImpl()`, if it doesn't make sense to do this.
2. Inheritance is a very strong form of coupling between classes. When you put function implementations in a base class you make strong assumptions about how derived classes should operate, that are difficult to change later. e.g. In this case, we cannot attempt to power-on a machine twice. Can we be sure this is always the case?  e.g. my mobile phone does something when you press the power on button when it is already powered up. It is often better to inherit from pure interfaces (e.g. `IMachine`) so that concrete classes can make these decisions for themselves, and this also avoids the virtual method problem.
3. It is also sometimes a good idea to reconsider the model here. What does it mean to 'destroy' a machine? When I 'destroy' a real-world machine, it probably does not have the ability to run a complete power-down sequence, so should a virtual machine call `powerOffImpl()` in the destructor anyway? Another way to think about it, is to consider that the lifetime of the machine is likely different from the on-off lifetime. They are different things, so perhaps they should be modelled differently. In this case I would consider having a separate `MachineSession` object to model the on-off lifetime. The `MachineSession` constructor takes an instance of `IMachine` and performs `IMachine.powerOn()`, and in its destructor calls `IMachine.powerOff()` (assuming powerOff gives the noexcept guarantee, or you protect this with a `try`/`catch`). This also avoids the need for `m_isPoweredOn`, because if you have a valid `MachineSession` then you know that the machine is powered up.